# Two GPIOs sharing the same hardware IO with 12V

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, output, input

I have a project where due to hardware restrictions I had to incorporate two MCU GPIOs under one wire.

Both serve the input and output for a 12 V signal. While the output is being pulled low, the I/O wire only has around 9 V output which is normal, because the voltage is being divided to the input (around 3.8 V, and yes, I know the input is being pulled high which is what I intended to do as well), but 9 V is not sufficient and the requirement is at least 12 V.

From the schematics I am drawing the only way to fix it is to raise V1 to 16 V, but that's not viable in my solution. Any alternative suggestions?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fstsdB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is the external "12V input" open drain? Otherwise you have a short when it's at 12V while Q1 is turned on. As for your question, any reason you can't just make R6 an order of magnitude larger?

Comment: @Unimportant oh right you just reminded me when I was about to say it could be fixed with R6 to 1Mohm. As for the first question, I didn't realize it could be shorted. I'm still new in the electricals.

Comment: Yes, it's a weird problem to have in the first place - very much looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Unimportant wouldn't it be like having two 12V sources connected in parallel in the circuit?  Why it would be a short?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to output LOW (=ground, Q1 turned on) while the external device is outputting 12V ?

Comment: @Unimportant it has a clear path between Q1 and the external so it would short right though because there are no resistor in the way

Comment: In the future, please use the built-in CircuitLab editor on this site. This allows the history of the circuit to be available, enables paid features for everyone, and takes care of inserting images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @Unimportant 's reminding advice, raise R6 to 1 Mohm and put an extra 4.7k resistor between external and Q1 would fix the shorting potential and the output voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fShKM9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: R6 and R7 could be a 4:1 voltage divider (1 Meg and 330k) so GPIO1 would be 3V when EXT_12V is high. Thus D2 would not need to clamp the input, although the diodes would offer additional protection. Perhaps they should be Schottky types?

Comment: @PStechPaul yes, in the actual schematics a BAT54S is used to replace D1 and D2.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a small SMD footprint, you can use a prebiased transistor pair, one NPN and one PNP with resistors in a single SOT-6 package.
MUN5311DW1 or PIMD3,115 or IMD3AT108 would match here. I use them up to 50 mA load current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmb5hY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The difference to your circuit is, that this one provides active high output and just a resistive load to GND.
So, if inactive, an other external source can feed EXT_IO and deliver "high" to the MCU.

A disadvantage is, that the output has no overcurrent protection. The PNP will deliver a bit more than 100 mA during short circuit here, which may be OK for some ms.